# returning value from subreport in a Table in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table in my main report which is created from a different dataset. And there is one subReport in that table element. 
I want to do some arithmetic operations in my table. Like the value returned my the subReport will be added or subtracted with another value in the table. But if want to return any variable from my subReport in that table element. I have to add the variable in the main report, not in the dataset I created for the table. And returning any value to the table element is giving a NullPointer exception.